# Identifying Duplicate in Set

Tags: java, set, duplicates

How does a set know that the entered value is a duplicate? I know that set ignores the repeated value but how does it know the value is repeated?

Comment: Sorry I am referring to set in Java

Answer (score 0):

It first *searches* the entered value in the set. If the search returns that there's an element of the set that is equal to the entered value, then this one won't be inserted.

This search is performed in a way that depends on the `Set` implementation. Simply put, i.e. a `HashSet` will use entered value's `hashCode()` method to find a bucket in its underlying array, and then entered value's `equals()` method to check for equality among elements that reside on that bucket. For `TreeSet`, a `Comparator` is used.

In short, the algorithm to search if a `Set` contains a value depends on its implementation.